# Migrating to the WebApi 2.2 RC and getting Response Status 406 (not acceptable)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, odata, asp.net-web-api2

I migrated to the WebAPI 2.2 RC (Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi -Version 5.2.0-rc) and I since them I get only 406 (Not Acceptable) as status response on all my queries, for example:

```
http://localhost:7923/api/Quotes(1)
```

[image: Status 406]

OData Service Configuration

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        config.EnableSystemDiagnosticsTracing();
        config.MapODataServiceRoute("api", "api", CreateEdmModel());
    }

    private static IEdmModel CreateEdmModel()
    {
        var odataModelBuilder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();

        odataModelBuilder.EntitySet<Tag>("Tags");
        odataModelBuilder.EntitySet<Author>("Authors");
        EntitySetConfiguration<Quote> quoteEntitySetConfiguration = odataModelBuilder.EntitySet<Quote>("Quotes");

        FunctionConfiguration getQuotesRandomFunction = quoteEntitySetConfiguration.EntityType.Collection.Function("Random");
        getQuotesRandomFunction.Parameter<int>("count");
        getQuotesRandomFunction.ReturnsCollectionFromEntitySet<Quote>("Quotes");

        return odataModelBuilder.GetEdmModel();
    }
}
```

QuotesController

```
public class QuotesController : ODataController
{
    private WhatAQuoteDb db = new WhatAQuoteDb();

    [ODataRoute("Default.Random(count={count})")]
    [EnableQuery]
    public IHttpActionResult GetQuotesRandom(int count)
    {
        return Ok(db.Quotes.OrderBy(quote => Guid.NewGuid()).Take(count));
    }

    // GET: odata/Quotes
    [EnableQuery]
    public IQueryable<Quote> GetQuotes()
    {
        return db.Quotes;
    }

    // GET: odata/Quotes(5)
    [EnableQuery]
    public SingleResult<Quote> GetQuote([FromODataUri] int key)
    {
        return SingleResult.Create(db.Quotes.Where(quote => quote.Id == key));
    }

    // PUT: odata/Quotes(5)
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Put([FromODataUri] int key, Quote quote)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        if (key != quote.Id)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        db.Entry(quote).State = EntityState.Modified;

        try
        {
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            if (!QuoteExists(key))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return Updated(quote);
    }

    // POST: odata/Quotes
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post(Quote quote)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        db.Quotes.Add(quote);
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();

        return Created(quote);
    }

    // PATCH: odata/Quotes(5)
    [AcceptVerbs("PATCH", "MERGE")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Patch([FromODataUri] int key, Delta<Quote> patch)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        Quote quote = await db.Quotes.FindAsync(key);
        if (quote == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        patch.Patch(quote);

        try
        {
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            if (!QuoteExists(key))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return Updated(quote);
    }

    // DELETE: odata/Quotes(5)
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Delete([FromODataUri] int key)
    {
        Quote quote = await db.Quotes.FindAsync(key);
        if (quote == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        db.Quotes.Remove(quote);
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();

        return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
    }

    // GET: odata/Quotes(5)/Author
    [EnableQuery]
    public SingleResult<Author> GetAuthor([FromODataUri] int key)
    {
        return SingleResult.Create(db.Quotes.Where(m => m.Id == key).Select(m => m.Author));
    }

    // GET: odata/Quotes(5)/Tags
    [EnableQuery]
    public IQueryable<Tag> GetTags([FromODataUri] int key)
    {
        return db.Quotes.Where(m => m.Id == key).SelectMany(m => m.Tags);
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    private bool QuoteExists(int key)
    {
        return db.Quotes.Count(e => e.Id == key) > 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: do you know how to get the RTM nightly bits? See directions on - https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Use%20Nightly%20Builds.

More specifically we (Web API team) are going to take a quick look, and get back to you shortly. Thanks for bringing this up.

Comment: we couldn't repro the problem based on the code in this post. We tried this with RC and the nightly build, but it worked fine. Could you provide us with more details or a repro project?

Comment: I used the official NuGet Packages https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi/5.2.0-rc.

Comment: I can provide for you the whole solution, there is everything you need to start. Or how can I otherwise support you?

Comment: [Here](http://1drv.ms/1kGT2qp) is the solution.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I checked your solution and found that you used service reference.

However adding service reference doesn't support OData V4 and the version in your generated code is V3.

You can try OData T4 code generator to generate client code.

Check the blog below:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/odatateam/archive/2014/03/11/how-to-use-odata-client-code-generator-to-generate-client-side-proxy-class.aspx

---

***Update:***

I checked your solution again and found the problem:

**The ODataController you used is V3!**

If you want the V4 version, you need to change the using namespace in your controller cs file

From

```
using System.Web.Http.OData;
```

To

```
using System.Web.OData;
```

What is more, there is other problem that the following template is invalid when I start up the project.

```
[ODataRoute("Default.Random(count={count})")]
```

I guest that the random function you defined is a function import and you should define like this:

```
FunctionConfiguration getQuotesRandomFunction = odataModelBuilder.Function("Random");
```

And the function import should not add namespace and the template should be:

```
[ODataRoute("Random(count={count})")]
```

Let me know if you have other problems.

Comment: I use Service Reference on the client side and the reason why this is in version 3 is because I didn't migrate client since the WebApi returns 406 status code

Comment: But thanks to me remind that client generation don't work with the OData V4

Comment: Great help, but can I find somewhere when and how to use the different function definitions: service level (unbounded),  collection level (bounded to collection) or entity level (bounded to the entity) as described [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/03/13/getting-started-with-asp-net-web-api-2-2-for-odata-v4-0.aspx)? I would to bind this method to the collection, with your proposal it is bound to the service level

Comment: function sample https://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/WebApi/OData/v4/ODataFunctionSample/ReadMe.txt and the action sample https://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/WebApi/OData/v4/ODataActionsSample/ReadMe.txt

Comment: This is what I found before but what I did wrong to bind the function in my example? Can you pls. provide me example how to bind the function in my solution to the collection?

Comment: Define the function: quoteEntitySetConfiguration.EntityType.Collection.Function("Random"); Write odata route: [ODataRoute("Quotes/WhatAQuote.Repository.Quotes.Db.Random(count={count})")] Send request: Get ~/Quotes/WhatAQuote.Repository.Quotes.Db.Random(count=10)

Comment: But it is means that the namespace must be included all the time?

Comment: Yes. The namespace must be included for bound function/action. For unbound function/action, the namespace must not be included. It follows odata v4 protocol.

Comment: But why is in all examples used "Default" and what it is mean?

Comment: Oh sorry, my namespace is incorrect. "Default" is the correct one. The default namespace of function/action is "Default". If you want to change it, you need to set: modelBuilder.Namespace = "NewNamespace"

Comment: Ok so what was than wrong in my registration code before?

Comment: I get it, I was missing _Quotes/_ so the correct Route looks like _[ODataRoute("Quotes/Default.Random(count={count})")]_

Comment: The issue with the wrong namespace and scaffolding is  still there